# Proof of Absolute Convergence of Power Series

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, power-series

Any tip on how to prove the absolute convergence. I tried to assign a series function for An and work my way through that, but I was wondering if there is a more efficient method?

The picture got cut off, the question is asking to prove if the second power series is also absolutely convergent, with n greater than/equal to 2

[image]

Comment: These are not power series, these are ordinary numerical series. To answer the question, note that $\frac{n}{{n - 1}} \le 2$.

Comment: Hint: $\frac{n}{n-1} = 1+\frac{1}{n-1}$

Comment: A similar question was asked recently: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4107460/42969.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I will try to use the hint

Comment: @MartinR Actually, originally it was the same question but the OP changed it at some point without mentioning it. Just look at some of the answers.